# Ubuntu mounting issue (16LTS - Upgraded from 14 4 months back)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, ext4

So we were having a problem with snapd so we tried stopping and starting the instance - snapd froze up. We then tried to stop it the command we ran with snapd (snapd stop [instance]) but it didn't work. Connected via lish and it was frozen - machine completely froze up. So we were forced to reset it.

System boots again and docker, snapd, and landscape (a load of failed to start LSB errors). We realised that snapd, docker and landscape all had error that said: `Failed to mount ...`

E.g snapd: 
`Failed to mount Mount unit for core, revision 5145`

rocketchat-server - a snap app: `Failed to mount Mount unit for rocketchat-server, revision 1311.`

etc.

Errors from systemd on boot:

```
Aug 12 20:49:10 xxx.xxx.co.uk systemd-modules-load[207]: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.17.14-x86_64-linode113/modules.dep.bin'

Aug 12 20:49:10 xxx.xxx.co.uk systemd-modules-load[207]: Failed to lookup alias 'lp': Function not implemented
```

---

On linode running Ubuntu 16 (Upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04LTS)

FS is ext4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with linodes latest kernel missing OverlayFS, these are `4.17.14-x86-linode132` and `4.17.14-x86_64-linode113`.

I recommend that you use GRUB 2 or linode110